# Add Contact TextField how To

Tags: objective-c, xcode, textview, contacts, addition

i have a short question, how would i implement a "add contact" like TextView to my app like its in the Message app of the iPhone

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [MFMessageComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009668)

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a `textView` for the user to type in contact name.
2. You can get that button by adding in the interface builder, and button type "Add", and in the `IBAction` navigate it to the viewController populating the `NativeAddressBook`.
3. Add a `UIScrollView` beneath the `textView`, which will responsible for loading contacts.

Comment: the problem is I dont want to select acontact from my address book, i want to use my own "adress book"